# Edit password of user in admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I've overwrite "save_model" method to manage user's password in my admin's panel application. What I want is:

- Create a new random password when I create new user (if password field is empty)
- Encrypt the password (if I set it)
- Use user's password (if I change user but not set the password)

How can I define the last condition?

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not change and (not form.cleaned_data['password']) :
        password = User.objects.make_random_password()
        obj.set_password(password)
    elif form.cleaned_data['password'] :
        obj.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
    else
        ?
    super(UserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all this a bit too late. The user creation form won't even allow you to post a form without fields `password1` and `password2` filled in. If those fields are empty you will never even get to `UserAdmin.save_model()` method.

But you can override the user creation form's `save()` method, in it allow password fields to be empty and set random password if fields are empty (or use user's password if entered).

As a bonus, this code keeps in place form validation if user entered the password (password mismatch) as well as checking `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` (all except `'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'` since empty password field mean 0 chars).

```
### admin.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].required = False
        self.fields['password2'].required = False

    def _clean_form(self):
        super()._clean_form()

        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if password1 != password2:
            self.add_error('password2', self.error_messages['password_mismatch'])

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)

        user_password = self.cleaned_data["password1"]

        if not user_password:
            user_password = User.objects.make_random_password()

        user.set_password(user_password)

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```